# how to use CTR as dependent variable for a logistic regression (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to use a logistic regression to forecast the click Through rate (CTR) of advertisements. As independent variables i use variables like placement and different binary variables on the creative. As dependent variable i want to use the CTR but i don't know how to do this because i need a binary variable as dependent variable for a logistic regression. A small example of the variables is have for the dependent variables are shown below.

My question is how can i use these variables to construct a logistic regression? Preferably in Python.

```
Clicks : 1148, 9952, 1329
Impressions : 251091, 1051109, 208390
CTR : 0.457, 0.947, 0.638
```

Thank you in advance

The code i used was:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
logisticRegr.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions = logisticRegr.predict(x_test) # x here is a matrix of independent mostly binary variables. Y = CTR which is a variable ranging between 0 and 1
```

The error i got was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3442, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-16-d7379bff0c70>", line 2, in <module> logisticRegr.fit(x_train, y_train) File "site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_logistic.py",
line 1204, in fit check_classification_targets(y) File site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py",
line 207, in check_classification_targets raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post the code you have used, the exact error you get and what would be the expected result.

Comment: Would you mind edit your post and format the code to make it readable a usable by the community.

Comment: The error comes from the fact that CTR is a continuous variable in your example where it must be binary (only 0 and 1).

Comment: Yess. But i would like to know how can i transform for example the CTR so i could still use a logistic regression to forecast the CTR

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the very nature of CTR variable which is continuous where it must be binary (0 or 1). Changing your data in your MCVE, the model trains et predicts as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

data = {
    "clicks": [1148, 9952, 1329],
    "impressions": [251091, 1051109, 208390],
    #"CTR": [0.457, 0.947, 0.638],
    "CTR": [0, 1, 1] 
}

X = pd.DataFrame(data)
y = X.pop("CTR") 

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train.values, y_train.values)
y_hat = model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Yes but now you lose all the information that is caught in the initial CTR. I would like a model where i somehow keep the infromation from the initial CTR